# Can't build boost on linux with bz2 support

Tags: c++, boost, bz2

Downloaded boost 1.66, unbzipped, launching bootstrap:

```
Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:
    ./b2
```

b2 reports:

```
...blablabla..
- zlib                     : yes (cached)
- bzip2                    : yes (cached)
...blablabla..
The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
    /home/steve/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib
...blablabla..
```

No errors during build, only warnings. I am looking into /home/steve/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib, but there is no files with *bz* in their name. On windows prebuilt binaries I have:

```
boost_bzip2-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_66.dll
boost_bzip2-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_66.lib
boost_bzip2-vc140-mt-x64-1_66.dll
boost_bzip2-vc140-mt-x64-1_66.lib
```

As a result my project builds fine on Windows and fails on Linux because of missing bz2 dependencies. Any ideas?

My linux is ubuntu 14.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what I've found out is that on Linux and Windows you need different libraries for bz2 streams to function. I am using cmake and this is how I've solved it:

```
if (MSVC)
    find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem bzip2 REQUIRED)
endif()
if(LINUX)
    find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem iostreams REQUIRED)
endif()
```

otherwise linker produces errors both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer your question. I mean, what you asked us was what you _thought_ was the cause of the problem, not the actual problem. Consider splitting the two questions, accepting the other answer here and writing a separate question+answer on the the project settings issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas?

Yup. You're looking for ghosts. On linux, `libz` and `libbz2` are the packaged versions by default:

```
cd custom/boost_1.66.0/
ldd ldd stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.66.0
```

Prints

> `linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe9708000)`
>   `libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fc3399af000)`
>   **`libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007fc33979f000)`**
>
>   `liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fc33957d000)`
>   `libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc3391f5000)`
>   `libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc338fde000)`
>   `libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc338dc1000)`
>   `libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc3389f7000)`
>   `libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc3387f3000)`
>   `libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc3384ea000)`
>   `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc339de5000)`

The library is part of the ``libbz2-1.0` package as you can find with

```
dpkg --search /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0
libbz2-1.0:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0
```

So if you want to build boost with bzip2 support, make sure you installed the development pacakage:

```
sudo apt install libbz2-dev
```

In fact, I'm often "lazy" and just install the dependencies from the distro boost packages:

```
sudo apt build-dep libboost-all-dev
```

It looks like you got that part covered, so you were looking for "extra libraries" that donot exist.